# :checked is not working when checkbox input is not right next to the item that needs to be styled

Tags: html, css

Style element that is not next to checkbox or label when checkbox is checked.

For example please see the code snippet below. I would like to make the text within div3 red when the #trigger checkbox is checked. I want to use pure css, no jQuery. The only way I can get it to work is if I move the checkbox above div3.

```css
#trigger:checked+.div1 + .div2 > .div3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="trigger" type="checkbox">
<div class="div1">
    <label for="trigger">
      CHECKBOX LABEL
    </label>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">ABCD</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, it's your expectations that are wrong. See the duplicate post for details about the next-sibling/adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator.

Comment: If you can't change the structure of your HTML you can't do what you want with CSS alone as there's no parent selector.

Comment: this is where the "cascading" part of CSS comes into play -- .div3 isn't below #trigger ... it's a (i guess) cousin (element ^ parent -> sibling - child). The adjacent sibling selector ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors ) would work on `<label for="trigger">` You can use styles to select neighboring elements (siblings) or child elements

Comment: @Doug so is there any selector that could make it possible or is + and changing the html structure my only option?

Comment: Not in any way that I am aware of -- your best bet would be to change the structure or add in some JS to detect the change on #trigger and then do something to .div3

Comment: @Doug I actually figured out with a small sacrafice which is fine. Moved the input to the outside of everything and then used a double plus. Does this make sense? Please see my updated sample.

Comment: Sounds like a good fix -- happy coding.